How can we capture update done with optimizer.step() in an elegant way?
I want to implement a method to monitor in Tensorboard the update-to-data ratio during training with PyTorch, following an idea mentioned in Karpathy's video. I've come up with a solution, but I'm looking for a more elegant and configurable approach.
The current implementation directly modifies the training loop as follows:
for step, batch in data_loader:
    x, y = batch
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        if param.requires_grad and "weight" in name:
            param.data_before_step = param.data.clone()
    output = model(x)
    loss = loss_fn(output, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    lr_scheduler.step()
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        if hasattr(param, "data_before_step"):
            update = param.data - param.data_before_step
            update_to_data = (update.std() / param.data_before_step.std()).log10().item()
            summary_writer.add_scalar(f"Update:data ratio {name}", update_to_data, epoch * len(data_loader) + step)
            param.data_before_step = param.data.clone()

However, this approach adds code directly within the training loop, which can clutter the code and if we want to make it configurable, if-else statements are needed which clutter the code even more.
I've also explored using PyTorch hooks to achieve this. I've successfully implemented a hook to track gradients:
class GradToDataRatioHook:
    def __init__(self, name, param, start_step, summary_writer):
        self.name = name
        self.param = param
        self.summary_writer = summary_writer
        self.grads = []
        self.grads_to_data = []
        self.param.update_step = start_step

    def __call__(self, grad):
        self.grads.append(grad.std().item())
        self.grads_to_data.append((grad.std() / (self.param.data.std() + 1e-5)).log10().item())
        self.summary_writer.add_scalar(f"Grad {self.name}", self.grads[-1], self.param.update_step)
        self.summary_writer.add_scalar(f"Grad:data ratio {self.name}", self.grads_to_data[-1], self.param.update_step)
        self.param.update_step += 1

However, implementing a similar hook to capture updates seems tricky. As far as I understand, param.register_hook(...) registers the hook, which is called when the gradient is calculated, i.e., before optimizer.step() is called. While the gradient and learning rate provide a direct value of an update for standard SGD, modern optimizers like Adam make the update process a bit more complicated. I'm seeking a solution that captures updates in an optimizer-agnostic way, preferably with PyTorch hooks. However, any suggestions or alternative approaches would be also greatly appreciated.

Probably the easiest way to do this is to dump the param groups and state dict of the optimizer after every backward call. This will let you capture the parameters, gradients and optimizer state.
The code below shows an example with a simple MLP, but the log_state function should work for all models so long as the param groups/state dict don't have multiple levels of nesting.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# example model
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.fc1(x)
        pred = self.fc2(self.relu(h))
        return pred

def log_state(opt):
    output = {}

    # log state dict
    state_dict = {}
    for key, value in opt.state_dict().items():
        if key == 'state':
            state_dict[key] = {}
            for state_key, state_value in value.items():
                state_dict[key][state_key] = {}
                for k, v in state_value.items():
                    if torch.is_tensor(v):
                        state_dict[key][state_key][k] = v.cpu().clone() # move tensor to cpu
                    else:
                        state_dict[key][state_key][k] = v
        else:
            state_dict[key] = value

    output['state_dict'] = state_dict

    # log param groups
    param_groups = []
    for group in opt.param_groups:
        param_group = {key: value for key, value in group.items() if key != 'params'}
        param_group['params'] = []
        param_group['param_grads'] = []
        for param in group['params']:
            param_group['params'].append(param.data.cpu().clone()) # move tensor to cpu
            # log gradients
            if param.grad is not None:
                param_group['param_grads'].append(param.grad.data.cpu().clone()) # move tensor to cpu
            else:
                param_group['param_grads'].append(None)

        param_groups.append(param_group)

    output['param_groups'] = param_groups
    
    return output



net = MLP(64, 20, 10)

opt = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

state_log = {}
for i in range(5):
    x = torch.randn(8, 64)
    y = torch.randn(8,10)
    p = net(x)
    loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(p, y)
    opt.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    state_log[i] = log_state(opt) # log optimizer state every step
    opt.step()

The code logs after backward to grab gradients. You could add additional logging after step, but the values updated after step (params, optimizer averages, etc) will be captured on the next iteration. You can also use values from one iteration to recreate the next. For example, with Adam:
step = 2

old_state = state_log[step]
new_state = state_log[step+1]

# adam params
b1 = 0.9
b2 = 0.999
eps = 1e-8
lr = 1e-3

w = old_state['param_groups'][0]['params'][0]
g = old_state['param_groups'][0]['param_grads'][0]

m_old = old_state['state_dict']['state'][0]['exp_avg']
v_old = old_state['state_dict']['state'][0]['exp_avg_sq']

m = b1 * m_old + (1-b1)*g
v = b2 * v_old + (1-b2)*(g.pow(2))

m_hat = m.div(1-b1**(step+1))
v_hat = v.div(1-b2**(step+1))

w_new = w - lr * m_hat / (torch.sqrt(v_hat) + eps)

torch.allclose(w_new, new_state['param_groups'][0]['params'][0])
> True

